# How does printf(3+"excellent"+4) this line run?

Tags: c, string, printf

I don't understand why the output is **`nt`** in this program.
Can anyone explain this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    printf(3+"excellent"+4); //output is  "nt"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is printing the string starting from position`7` in the string literal `"excellent"`

Comment: ...because `"excellent"` resolves to a **pointer** to that *string literal* and then `7` is added to the pointer.

Comment: Addition has the ["commutative property"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) where `(3 + "excellent" + 4)` is equal to `(4 + "excellent" + 3)` and to `("excellent" + 4 + 3)` etc.

Comment: In C, all pointers are treated as *memory locations*, and `const char*` being a pointer also holds a memory location. Now, when you do `3+"excellent"+4`, it shifts the address by 7 bytes (4 + 3 = 7), and it becomes `nt`

Comment: @WeatherVane This for your benefit not as much as the OP's:  And as a consequence the subscript operator is commutative as well, even if the syntax is asymmetrical: `4["abcd"] == 0`...

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica thank you for the good point, I almost mentioned that `x[y]` is the same as `y[x]` but more than one comment will take.

Answer (score 9):

`"excellent"` is an array of type `char[10]`, the elements of which are the 9 letters of the word and the terminating `'\0'`. And then, [C11 6.3.2.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3),

> 3. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]

i.e. it is converted to a pointer to the first character of the string, (`e`), and then has the type `char *`.

Now we have two additions:

```
(3 + (char *)"excellent") + 4
```

The C standard says (simplified, [C11 6.5.6p8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8)) that when adding an integer and a pointer together, the result will be a pointer of the same type, and will be interpreted so that if the pointer `p` was pointing to element `n` of an array, then `p + m` will result in a pointer that will point to element `n + m` of the same array, or one past the end, or, if `n + m` is outside the bounds of the array or one past the end, the behaviour is undefined.

I.e. `3 + "excellent"` will give a pointer that will point to the 2nd letter `e` of `excellent`. Now of course since the parenthesized expression has type `char *` and it points to the element 3 of the array, if we add 4 to it, we get a pointer that points to the element 7, i.e. 8th letter, the `n`.

```
 <-------------- char [10] -------------->

 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | e | x | c | e | l | l | e | n | t | \0|
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   ^           ^               ^
   |           |               |
   first character, "excellent" after lvalue conversion
               |               |
               + 3 + "excellent"
                               |
                               + 3 + "excellent" + 4
```

Now finally, what will happen when we call `printf` giving such a pointer as an argument? `printf` will consider the argument as being a pointer to a first character of a null terminated string that is the format string. Other than special sequences that start with `%`, all characters are copied verbatim to the output until the terminating null is met.

---

Another way to look into these is to remember that

```
*(a + b)
```

is equal to

```
a[b] (or even b[a])
```

and since `&*x` is equivalent to `x`,

```
&*(a + b) == (a + b) == (b + a) == &a[b] == &b[a]`
```

and we get that

```
3 + "excellent" + 4
```

equals

```
&"excellent"[3] + 4
```

which equals

```
&"excellent"[3 + 4]
```

i.e.

```
&"excellent"[7]
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, but I just had a thought that I should write a Python program for them...

Answer (score 7):

This

```
printf(3+"excellent"+4);
```

Can be written in a little longer but a way more clear way:

```
const char *str = "excellent";
const char *to_print = str + 3 + 4; // equivalent to &str[7] which points to 'n'
printf(to_print); // or printf("%s", to_print); which prints "nt"
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because it is printing everything after the 7th character. The plus tells it where to start the print. If you change it to `printf(2+"excellent"+4)` you get "ent"